# Using JavaScript so that when an image is clicked another element's position is changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am new at JavaScript and I am trying to create an event that when an  image is clicked on, the position of another image is changed.  I have an image hidden off screen to the left and I have a table of pictures on the center of the page.  I am trying to make it so that when an image in the table is clicked the hidden image slides out from the left.  I am trying to learn JavaScript and don't want to use JQuery yet.  Thank you in advanced for your help.

Here is the HTML and the CSS and the JavaScript follows:

HTML for the table:

```
  <table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><img onclick="sleepFunction()" src="01.jpg" height="180" width="120"></td>
      <td><img src="02.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="03.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="04.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="05.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="06.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="07.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="08.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="09.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

HTML for the image:

```
<div class = "sleepImage">
<img src = "sleeping.jpg" width= "490"/>
   </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 .sleepImage {
float: right;
position: absolute;
top: 108px;
left: -600px;
}
```

And here is the JavaScript Code:

```
function sleepFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("sleepImage").style.left = "300px";
}
```

Comment: [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a [_NodeList_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (or [_HTMLCollection_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) which is similar to an _Array_, not a _HTMLElement_. You probably wanted to access the item at index `0` of this list and set the style on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the sleepImage from a class to and id so your code should be

html

```
<div id = "sleepImage">
<img src = "sleeping.jpg" width= "490"/>
</div>
```

css

```
#sleepImage {
   /* your styles here */
}
```

js

```
function sleepFunction() { 
   document.getElementById("sleepImage").style.left = "300px";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, once I changed the classes (still getting my head around the difference between classes and Ids and made the above changes the code worked.

Comment: @Obi-wan you can think of a class as a group of elements. Where as an id should be unique and only given to one element. So a real word analogy might be at a school. All students are in Mrs.Smiths class. That would be the class and all rules would apply to all of them. But only Billy an id would follow rules specifically for Billy. Not the best example but hope that makes it a little more clear. Also if you could please accept my answer thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, still new to how its done around here.  And thank you for the analogy, it makes it somewhat clearer..

Answer (score 0):

Give an Id to your div (NameDiv) and edit your function :

```
document.getElementById("NameDiv").style.left = "300px";
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName('sleepImage') will return an array of all the elements that have the class name of sleepImage. You want the first element so add an index at the end.Something like below

```
function sleepFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("sleepImage")[0].style.left = "300px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you observe, the code that you have written is  :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sleepImage").style.left = "300px";
```

Did you observe the **getElementsByClassName**. As the name suggests, it returns elements and not an element. These elements are returned as a collection (similar to `arrays`). So you will need to iterate over the collection to get the element you are looking for.

The following code is what you need to use :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("sleepImage")[0].style.left = "300px";
```

See the demo below :

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName("sleepImage")[0].style.left = "300px";
});
```

```css
.sleepImage {
     position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td><img onclick="sleepFunction()" src="01.jpg" height="180" width="120" alt="selectorImage"/></td>
      <td><img src="02.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="03.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="04.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="05.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="06.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><img src="07.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="08.jpg" height="180" width="120"/></td>
      <td><img src="09.jpg" height="180" width="290"/></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
       </table>
<input type="button" value="Move Image" id="myBtn"/>
       <div class = "sleepImage">
<img src = "sleeping.jpg" width= "490" alt="sleepImage"/>
   </div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the getElementsByClassName it has made the differences a little clearer, I tried out your way and it also worked but I think I will just change from using the class to Id as it is much simpler for me to understand at this point.

Comment: @Obi-wan Glad to be helpful.In that case your code would need to be as `document.getElementById(".elementId").style.left = "300px";`